# Converting long numpy array for string efficiently

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have numpy array of 1,000 elements which I want to convert to strings.

I have tried:

```py
map(str, a)
```

It's very slow. Any other option? Thanks.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you're doing? You may be trying to solve the wrong problem. For example, if you're wanting to write formatted data from a numpy array to a file or a buffer of some sort, there are better ways.

Comment: I want to write it to a text file so and the write function accepts strings

Comment: Have a look at `numpy.savetxt` http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to write a numpy array to a text file, use [`numpy.savetxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html).  Based on your comment, this is what you want.

However, in the interest of answering your original question, there are faster ways to convert a numpy array to strings, if you can live with fixed-length strings.

For simple things, you can convert it to a fixed-length string array.

E.g.

```
import numpy as np

# Generate some random floating-point data
x = np.random.random(100)

# Convert it to fixed-length strings with a maximum length of 5 characters
y = x.astype('|S5')

print 'Original Array'
print x
print 'Converted to fixed-length strings'
print y
```

This outputs:

```
Original Array
[ 0.25669986  0.55193955  0.39582629  0.40559555  0.75836284  0.13031881
  0.84448005  0.20825593  0.32131777  0.5738351   0.72200185  0.14700912
  0.62306299  0.21549908  0.96927738  0.13327512  0.06948689  0.34436446
  0.58785565  0.58557563  0.3229981   0.0356056   0.67621536  0.07334146
  0.25804432  0.59477881  0.10382583  0.47255438  0.0747982   0.41586059
  0.54310507  0.68426668  0.14454108  0.62950246  0.30748958  0.56605352
  0.25072476  0.70945076  0.72311872  0.2357644   0.59668047  0.27536644
  0.96557189  0.97749755  0.95629738  0.15902741  0.32879056  0.60324024
  0.07463531  0.77562818  0.20181969  0.53088481  0.85723283  0.25163771
  0.06770161  0.45302361  0.3500556   0.37980214  0.87567327  0.94278158
  0.28586752  0.35682239  0.8746877   0.99562283  0.38323688  0.90561641
  0.64439454  0.53465359  0.37486244  0.33196021  0.99762377  0.29295412
  0.50162051  0.17312773  0.80100872  0.04233855  0.69062118  0.59194923
  0.65409137  0.25636784  0.40616824  0.82858658  0.90618301  0.87036914
  0.37534268  0.566982    0.55454063  0.75048023  0.56582157  0.62779239
  0.05196828  0.86418784  0.9862007   0.43015164  0.43576519  0.64918536
  0.99522735  0.81158283  0.02115479  0.47745413]
Converted to fixed-length strings
['0.256' '0.551' '0.395' '0.405' '0.758' '0.130' '0.844' '0.208' '0.321'
 '0.573' '0.722' '0.147' '0.623' '0.215' '0.969' '0.133' '0.069' '0.344'
 '0.587' '0.585' '0.322' '0.035' '0.676' '0.073' '0.258' '0.594' '0.103'
 '0.472' '0.074' '0.415' '0.543' '0.684' '0.144' '0.629' '0.307' '0.566'
 '0.250' '0.709' '0.723' '0.235' '0.596' '0.275' '0.965' '0.977' '0.956'
 '0.159' '0.328' '0.603' '0.074' '0.775' '0.201' '0.530' '0.857' '0.251'
 '0.067' '0.453' '0.350' '0.379' '0.875' '0.942' '0.285' '0.356' '0.874'
 '0.995' '0.383' '0.905' '0.644' '0.534' '0.374' '0.331' '0.997' '0.292'
 '0.501' '0.173' '0.801' '0.042' '0.690' '0.591' '0.654' '0.256' '0.406'
 '0.828' '0.906' '0.870' '0.375' '0.566' '0.554' '0.750' '0.565' '0.627'
 '0.051' '0.864' '0.986' '0.430' '0.435' '0.649' '0.995' '0.811' '0.021'
 '0.477']
```

This will be much faster, but you're limited to fixed-length strings. (Obviously, you can change the length. Just use `x.astype('|S10')` or whatever length you'd like.)

Again, though, if you're just wanting to write the data to a file, use `savetxt`.

Comment: And if you want a bit more control in the string conversion (concerning the original question, not saving to a file), you can use `np.mod.char` with string formatting. Ie, `np.char.mod('%.9f', x)` to get 9 decimals. This is quite useful because you don't need to choose the lenght, and if you have numbers of different magnitudes you'll avoid nasty surprises.

Comment: @jorgeca - Nice! I wasn't aware of `np.char.mod`.